# Install flutter on macos for using on Visual studio code

Tags: git, flutter, macos, dart, homebrew

I have an issue regarding installing **flutter** on macOS. I went through these steps already:

1.) typing `flutter doctor` gives:

```
zsh: command not found: flutter
```

2.) typing `which flutter` gives:

```
/Users/myName/Documents/Developer/flutter/bin/flutter
```

I entered this before:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/myName/Documents/Developer/flutter/bin"
```

3.) I checked a video and did `$ brew install git` but got zsh:

```
command not found: $
```

I do have a working homebrew

4.) I do not want to use **Android Studio**, I want to make it work on **Visual Studio Code**.

5.) When typing `cd ~ vim .zshrc`

I get errors as well. I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Did you make sure that there is an actual flutter folder in that path?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.